# Ubuntu Linux nvidia xserver DPMS working for anybody?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia-graphics-card, x-server, powersave

Can the Ubuntu Linux nvidia xserver powermizer feature use DPMS to trigger "Power Saving Mode" in my Acer LCD?

I switched this display from my Windows 8 HP machine to my Ubuntu Quantal Compaq machine. Power save on the Windows 8 machine worked fine - monitor powered off and woke up as defined in the configuration app.

In Ubuntu, only the display card shuts off - monitor is still lit and displays the "no input connected" floating box. That means it's drawing wattage. The Ubuntu box has an NVidia card with "Powermizer" which I assume speaks DPMS to tell the display to shut off. The display is an Acwer s201 and it features a "Power Saving Mode" that worked on Win 8, assume that's DPMS. Xserver driver from Nvidia is 304.116.

Unfortunately, 99% of tech board topics on this seem to be folks who want to -Disable- power saving features. Not me, I would like to save energy.

Is this an Ubuntu or an Nvidia defect?

Answer (score 0):

The root of this problem seems to vary, from research I've done so far.  In my case, on Ubuntu 16.04 with 367.57 drivers, `xset q` reports that "DPMS is Disabled".  If I manually run `xset dpms`, DPMS becomes enabled.

I haven't yet found a good way to automate this, though.  I found a report that adding `Option "DPMS"` to the Device section of xorg.conf might help, but it didn't help me.

I added that command to my .bashrc, because I start xterms a lot:

```
    case "$TERM" in
    xterm*|rxvt*)
        xset dpms
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
    esac
```

But there has to be a better way.

Comment: Please edit your answer so you explain in detail how the author solves their problem.

Comment: For my case, further ubuntu upgrades (as of bionic beaver) seem to have enabled the power saving feature on my monitor. And I must say as the OP, I only was asking if anybody has seen it work, proving that it COULD work. I got crickets; seems like that means "No" during the period I asked.